# How to remove user settings in Cloud9?

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I'm playing with C9's SDK a little, trying to write a simple plugin. according to [Settings and Preferences](https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/settings-and-preferences) as well as [settings](https://apidoc.c9.io/c9v3/#!/api/settings), one can store settings in the `user` context using something like

```
settings.set("user/my-plugin/@someKey", 100);
```

no problem with that. the problem is that apparently there's no obvious way to remove a setting. In a desperate try, I tried to find the path for the file in which user settings are stored and remove the settings manually, according to the code in [`settings.js`](https://github.com/c9/core/blob/1412e15569b76445f2aa9049c61655b69aa7a105/plugins/c9.core/settings.js#L48), they should be in `~/.c9/user.settings`, but no such file exists. I also never defined `userConfigPath` in `package.json`. so can I remove a user setting? how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set it to undefined to remove `settings.set("user/my-plugin/@someKey", undefined);`
Or use `cloud9>open your user settings` menu item.

`~/.c9/user.settings` is used only in standalone version, on c9.io user settings are stored in a database outside of user vm.

Comment: thanks a lot! is that documented somewhere? am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, where is this officially documented? I only see ‘~/.c9/user.settings‘ , and only when in https://ide.c9.io/.. I do Preferences -> ‘Manually edit these settings by clicking on this link: user.settings.’ then Save As --shows that part is real but hardly documentation & doesn't cover the ‘in a database’. So I web search but no lock: tried http://google.com/search?q=Cloud9+OR+C9.io+"user.settings" but only found official talk of ‘.c9/project.settings’ (in https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/settings-and-preferences & https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/customizing-cloud9 ). Pls, where's the docs?